# How to Fake Ctrl-C?

Tags: bash

When I run an mp3 command by doing `mpg123 Thunder.mp3`, it runs in a loop. Is there any way to fake a Control-C keyboard interrupt via bash script?

Comment: Short answer: `pkill mpg123`

Answer (score 3):

(I use `mpg123` as example program)
As the comment say, you need

```
$ pkill mpg123
```

Alternative:

```
$ killall mpg123
```

Also, you'd better check if the process is indeed running:

```
$ pgrep -f mpg123
```

Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542550/how-to-kill-processes-in-bash
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160924/how-can-i-kill-a-process-by-name-instead-of-pid